# Electron can't load external SVG files when URLs are prefixed with "//"

Tags: javascript, typescript, electron

I have a component which loads SVG files from a remote source using URLs like this:

```
<img src="//cdn.image-hosting.com/sample.svg" />
```

As you can see, the URL starts with `//`. In development, everything works as expected, however, when I build the application and run the production version, Electron tries to load those URLs from the disk (`file://`) instead of requesting them from the remote server.

I'm using Webpack, but that does not change the URL; it is still the same in production as in development.

This is my configuration for the production build:

```
// Webpack uses `publicPath` to determine where the app is being served from.
// It requires a trailing slash, or the file assets will get an incorrect path.
// const publicPath = paths.servedPath;
const publicPath = './';
// Some apps do not use client-side routing with pushState.
// For these, "homepage" can be set to "." to enable relative asset paths.
const shouldUseRelativeAssetPaths = true // publicPath === './';
// Source maps are resource heavy and can cause out of memory issue for large source files.
const shouldUseSourceMap = process.env.GENERATE_SOURCEMAP !== 'false';
// Some apps do not need the benefits of saving a web request, so not inlining the chunk
// makes for a smoother build process.
const shouldInlineRuntimeChunk = process.env.INLINE_RUNTIME_CHUNK !== 'false';
// `publicUrl` is just like `publicPath`, but we will provide it to our app
// as %PUBLIC_URL% in `index.html` and `process.env.PUBLIC_URL` in JavaScript.
// Omit trailing slash as %PUBLIC_URL%/xyz looks better than %PUBLIC_URL%xyz.
const publicUrl = publicPath.slice(0, -1); // or '/' works
// Get environment variables to inject into our app.
const env = getClientEnvironment(publicUrl);

// Assert this just to be safe.
// Development builds of React are slow and not intended for production.
if (env.stringified['process.env'].NODE_ENV !== '"production"') {
  throw new Error('Production builds must have NODE_ENV=production.');
}

// Check if TypeScript is setup
const useTypeScript = fs.existsSync(paths.appTsConfig);

// style files regexes
const cssRegex = /\.css$/;
const cssModuleRegex = /\.module\.css$/;
const sassRegex = /\.(scss|sass)$/;
const sassModuleRegex = /\.module\.(scss|sass)$/;

// common function to get style loaders
const getStyleLoaders = (cssOptions, preProcessor) => {
  const loaders = [
    {
      loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
      options: Object.assign(
        {},
        shouldUseRelativeAssetPaths ? { publicPath: '../../' } : undefined
      ),
    },
    {
      loader: require.resolve('css-loader'),
      options: cssOptions,
    },
    {
      // Options for PostCSS as we reference these options twice
      // Adds vendor prefixing based on your specified browser support in
      // package.json
      loader: require.resolve('postcss-loader'),
      options: {
        // Necessary for external CSS imports to work
        // https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2677
        ident: 'postcss',
        plugins: () => [
          require('postcss-flexbugs-fixes'),
          require('postcss-preset-env')({
            autoprefixer: {
              browsers: [
                '>1%',
                'last 4 versions',
                'Firefox ESR',
                'not ie < 9', // React doesn't support IE8 anyway
              ],
              flexbox: 'no-2009',
            },
            stage: 3,
          }),
        ],
        sourceMap: shouldUseSourceMap,
      },
    },
  ];
  if (preProcessor) {
    loaders.push({
      loader: require.resolve(preProcessor),
      options: {
        sourceMap: shouldUseSourceMap,
      },
    });
  }
  return loaders;
};

// This is the production configuration.
// It compiles slowly and is focused on producing a fast and minimal bundle.
// The development configuration is different and lives in a separate file.
module.exports = {
  mode: 'production',
  // Don't attempt to continue if there are any errors.
  bail: true,
  // We generate sourcemaps in production. This is slow but gives good results.
  // You can exclude the *.map files from the build during deployment.
  devtool: shouldUseSourceMap ? 'source-map' : false,
  // In production, we only want to load the app code.
  entry: [paths.appIndexJs],
  output: {
    // The build folder.
    path: paths.appBuild,
    // Generated JS file names (with nested folders).
    // There will be one main bundle, and one file per asynchronous chunk.
    // We don't currently advertise code splitting but Webpack supports it.
    filename: 'static/js/[name].[chunkhash:8].js',
    chunkFilename: 'static/js/[name].[chunkhash:8].chunk.js',
    // We inferred the "public path" (such as / or /my-project) from homepage.
    publicPath: publicPath,
    // Point sourcemap entries to original disk location (format as URL on Windows)
    devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate: info =>
      path
        .relative(paths.appSrc, info.absoluteResourcePath)
        .replace(/\\/g, '/'),
  },
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [
      new TerserPlugin({
        terserOptions: {
          parse: {
            // we want terser to parse ecma 8 code. However, we don't want it
            // to apply any minfication steps that turns valid ecma 5 code
            // into invalid ecma 5 code. This is why the 'compress' and 'output'
            // sections only apply transformations that are ecma 5 safe
            // https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/4234
            ecma: 8,
          },
          compress: {
            ecma: 5,
            warnings: false,
            // Disabled because of an issue with Uglify breaking seemingly valid code:
            // https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2376
            // Pending further investigation:
            // https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2/issues/2011
            comparisons: false,
            // Disabled because of an issue with Terser breaking valid code:
            // https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/5250
            // Pending futher investigation:
            // https://github.com/terser-js/terser/issues/120
            inline: 2,
          },
          mangle: {
            safari10: true,
          },
          output: {
            ecma: 5,
            comments: false,
            // Turned on because emoji and regex is not minified properly using default
            // https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2488
            ascii_only: true,
          },
        },
        // Use multi-process parallel running to improve the build speed
        // Default number of concurrent runs: os.cpus().length - 1
        parallel: true,
        // Enable file caching
        cache: true,
        sourceMap: shouldUseSourceMap,
      }),
      new OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin({
        cssProcessorOptions: {
          parser: safePostCssParser,
          map: shouldUseSourceMap
            ? {
              // `inline: false` forces the sourcemap to be output into a
              // separate file
              inline: false,
              // `annotation: true` appends the sourceMappingURL to the end of
              // the css file, helping the browser find the sourcemap
              annotation: true,
            }
            : false,
        },
      }),
    ],
    // Automatically split vendor and commons
    // https://twitter.com/wSokra/status/969633336732905474
    // https://medium.com/webpack/webpack-4-code-splitting-chunk-graph-and-the-splitchunks-optimization-be739a861366
    splitChunks: {
      chunks: 'all',
      name: false,
    },
    // Keep the runtime chunk seperated to enable long term caching
    // https://twitter.com/wSokra/status/969679223278505985
    runtimeChunk: true,
  },
  resolve: {
    // This allows you to set a fallback for where Webpack should look for modules.
    // We placed these paths second because we want `node_modules` to "win"
    // if there are any conflicts. This matches Node resolution mechanism.
    // https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/253
    modules: ['node_modules'].concat(
      // It is guaranteed to exist because we tweak it in `env.js`
      process.env.NODE_PATH.split(path.delimiter).filter(Boolean)
    ),
    // These are the reasonable defaults supported by the Node ecosystem.
    // We also include JSX as a common component filename extension to support
    // some tools, although we do not recommend using it, see:
    // https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/290
    // `web` extension prefixes have been added for better support
    // for React Native Web.
    // extensions: paths.moduleFileExtensions
    //   .map(ext => `.${ext}`)
    //   .filter(ext => useTypeScript || !ext.includes('ts')),
    extensions: [
      '.mjs',
      '.web.ts',
      '.ts',
      '.web.tsx',
      '.tsx',
      '.web.js',
      '.js',
      '.json',
      '.web.jsx',
      '.jsx',
      '.scss'
    ],
    alias: {
      // Support React Native Web
      // https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/08/a-glimpse-into-the-future-with-react-native-for-web/
      'react-native': 'react-native-web',
    },
    plugins: [
      // Adds support for installing with Plug'n'Play, leading to faster installs and adding
      // guards against forgotten dependencies and such.
      PnpWebpackPlugin,
      // Prevents users from importing files from outside of src/ (or node_modules/).
      // This often causes confusion because we only process files within src/ with babel.
      // To fix this, we prevent you from importing files out of src/ -- if you'd like to,
      // please link the files into your node_modules/ and let module-resolution kick in.
      // Make sure your source files are compiled, as they will not be processed in any way.
      new ModuleScopePlugin(paths.appSrc, [paths.appPackageJson]),
    ],
  },
  resolveLoader: {
    plugins: [
      // Also related to Plug'n'Play, but this time it tells Webpack to load its loaders
      // from the current package.
      PnpWebpackPlugin.moduleLoader(module),
    ],
  },
  module: {
    strictExportPresence: true,
    rules: [
      // Disable require.ensure as it's not a standard language feature.
      { parser: { requireEnsure: false } },

      // First, run the linter.
      // It's important to do this before Babel processes the JS.
      {
        test: /\.(js|mjs|jsx)$/,
        enforce: 'pre',
        use: [
          {
            options: {
              formatter: require.resolve('react-dev-utils/eslintFormatter'),
              eslintPath: require.resolve('eslint'),

            },
            loader: require.resolve('eslint-loader'),
          },
        ],
        include: paths.appSrc,
      },
      {
        // "oneOf" will traverse all following loaders until one will
        // match the requirements. When no loader matches it will fall
        // back to the "file" loader at the end of the loader list.
        oneOf: [
          // "url" loader works just like "file" loader but it also embeds
          // assets smaller than specified size as data URLs to avoid requests.
          {
            test: [/\.bmp$/, /\.svg$/, /\.gif$/, /\.jpe?g$/, /\.png$/],
            loader: require.resolve('url-loader'),
            options: {
              limit: 10000,
              name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]',
            },
          },
          // Process application JS with Babel.
          // The preset includes JSX, Flow, TypeScript and some ESnext features.
          {
            test: /\.(js|mjs|jsx|ts|tsx)$/,
            include: paths.appSrc,

            loader: require.resolve('babel-loader'),
            options: {
              customize: require.resolve(
                'babel-preset-react-app/webpack-overrides'
              ),

              plugins: [
                [
                  require.resolve('babel-plugin-named-asset-import'),
                  {
                    loaderMap: {
                      svg: {
                        ReactComponent: '@svgr/webpack?-prettier,-svgo![path]',
                      },
                    },
                  },
                ],
              ],
              cacheDirectory: true,
              // Save disk space when time isn't as important
              cacheCompression: true,
              compact: true,
            },
          },
          // Process any JS outside of the app with Babel.
          // Unlike the application JS, we only compile the standard ES features.
          {
            test: /\.(js|mjs)$/,
            exclude: /@babel(?:\/|\\{1,2})runtime/,
            loader: require.resolve('babel-loader'),
            options: {
              babelrc: false,
              configFile: false,
              compact: false,
              presets: [
                [
                  require.resolve('babel-preset-react-app/dependencies'),
                  { helpers: true },
                ],
              ],
              cacheDirectory: true,
              // Save disk space when time isn't as important
              cacheCompression: true,

              // If an error happens in a package, it's possible to be
              // because it was compiled. Thus, we don't want the browser
              // debugger to show the original code. Instead, the code
              // being evaluated would be much more helpful.
              sourceMaps: false,
            },
          },
          // "postcss" loader applies autoprefixer to our CSS.
          // "css" loader resolves paths in CSS and adds assets as dependencies.
          // `MiniCSSExtractPlugin` extracts styles into CSS
          // files. If you use code splitting, async bundles will have their own separate CSS chunk file.
          // By default we support CSS Modules with the extension .module.css
          {
            test: cssRegex,
            // include: APP_DIR,
            exclude: cssModuleRegex,
            loader: getStyleLoaders({
              importLoaders: 1,
              sourceMap: shouldUseSourceMap,
              camelCase: "only",
              localIdentName: '[hash:base64:10]'
            }),
            // Don't consider CSS imports dead code even if the
            // containing package claims to have no side effects.
            // Remove this when webpack adds a warning or an error for this.
            // See https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/6571
            sideEffects: true,
          },
          {
            test: cssRegex,
            include: MONACO_DIR,
            use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
            // Note: this won't work without `new ExtractTextPlugin()` in `plugins`.
          },
          // Adds support for CSS Modules (https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules)
          // using the extension .module.css
          {
            test: cssModuleRegex,
            loader: getStyleLoaders({
              importLoaders: 1,
              sourceMap: shouldUseSourceMap,
              modules: true,
              camelCase: "only",
              localIdentName: '[hash:base64:10]'
            }),
          },
          // Opt-in support for SASS. The logic here is somewhat similar
          // as in the CSS routine, except that "sass-loader" runs first
          // to compile SASS files into CSS.
          // By default we support SASS Modules with the
          // extensions .module.scss or .module.sass
          {
            test: sassRegex,
            exclude: sassModuleRegex,
            loader: getStyleLoaders(
              {
                modules: true,
                sourceMap: shouldUseSourceMap,
                camelCase: "only",
                localIdentName: '[hash:base64:10]'
              },
              'sass-loader'
            ),
            // Don't consider CSS imports dead code even if the
            // containing package claims to have no side effects.
            // Remove this when webpack adds a warning or an error for this.
            // See https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/6571
            sideEffects: true,
          },
          // Adds support for CSS Modules, but using SASS
          // using the extension .module.scss or .module.sass
          {
            test: sassModuleRegex,
            loader: getStyleLoaders(
              {
                importLoaders: 2,
                sourceMap: shouldUseSourceMap,
                modules: true,
                camelCase: "only",
                localIdentName: '[hash:base64:10]'
              },
              'sass-loader'
            ),
          },
          // "file" loader makes sure assets end up in the `build` folder.
          // When you `import` an asset, you get its filename.
          // This loader doesn't use a "test" so it will catch all modules
          // that fall through the other loaders.
          {
            loader: require.resolve('file-loader'),
            // Exclude `js` files to keep "css" loader working as it injects
            // it's runtime that would otherwise be processed through "file" loader.
            // Also exclude `html` and `json` extensions so they get processed
            // by webpacks internal loaders.
            exclude: [/\.(js|mjs|jsx|ts|tsx)$/, /\.html$/, /\.json$/],
            options: {
              name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]',
            },
          },
          // ** STOP ** Are you adding a new loader?
          // Make sure to add the new loader(s) before the "file" loader.
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    // Generates an `index.html` file with the <script> injected.
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      inject: true,
      template: paths.appHtml,
      minify: {
        removeComments: true,
        collapseWhitespace: true,
        removeRedundantAttributes: true,
        useShortDoctype: true,
        removeEmptyAttributes: true,
        removeStyleLinkTypeAttributes: true,
        keepClosingSlash: true,
        minifyJS: true,
        minifyCSS: true,
        minifyURLs: true,
      },
    }),
    // Inlines the webpack runtime script. This script is too small to warrant
    // a network request.
    shouldInlineRuntimeChunk &&
    new InlineChunkHtmlPlugin(HtmlWebpackPlugin, [/runtime~.+[.]js/]),
    // Makes some environment variables available in index.html.
    // The public URL is available as %PUBLIC_URL% in index.html, e.g.:
    // <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">
    // In production, it will be an empty string unless you specify "homepage"
    // in `package.json`, in which case it will be the pathname of that URL.
    new InterpolateHtmlPlugin(HtmlWebpackPlugin, env.raw),
    // This gives some necessary context to module not found errors, such as
    // the requesting resource.
    new ModuleNotFoundPlugin(paths.appPath),
    // Makes some environment variables available to the JS code, for example:
    // if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') { ... }. See `./env.js`.
    // It is absolutely essential that NODE_ENV was set to production here.
    // Otherwise React will be compiled in the very slow development mode.
    new webpack.DefinePlugin(env.stringified),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      // Options similar to the same options in webpackOptions.output
      // both options are optional
      filename: 'static/css/[contenthash:24].css',
      chunkFilename: 'static/css/[contenthash:24].chunk.css',
    }),
    // Generate a manifest file which contains a mapping of all asset filenames
    // to their corresponding output file so that tools can pick it up without
    // having to parse `index.html`.
    new ManifestPlugin({
      fileName: 'asset-manifest.json',
      publicPath: publicPath,
    }),
    // Moment.js is an extremely popular library that bundles large locale files
    // by default due to how Webpack interprets its code. This is a practical
    // solution that requires the user to opt into importing specific locales.
    // https://github.com/jmblog/how-to-optimize-momentjs-with-webpack
    // You can remove this if you don't use Moment.js:
    new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^\.\/locale$/, /moment$/),
    // Generate a service worker script that will precache, and keep up to date,
    // the HTML & assets that are part of the Webpack build.
    new WorkboxWebpackPlugin.GenerateSW({
      clientsClaim: true,
      exclude: [/\.map$/, /asset-manifest\.json$/],
      importWorkboxFrom: 'cdn',
      navigateFallback: publicUrl + '/index.html',
      navigateFallbackBlacklist: [
        // Exclude URLs starting with /_, as they're likely an API call
        new RegExp('^/_'),
        // Exclude URLs containing a dot, as they're likely a resource in
        // public/ and not a SPA route
        new RegExp('/[^/]+\\.[^/]+$'),
      ],
    }),
    new SWPrecacheWebpackPlugin({
      // By default, a cache-busting query parameter is appended to requests
      // used to populate the caches, to ensure the responses are fresh.
      // If a URL is already hashed by Webpack, then there is no concern
      // about it being stale, and the cache-busting can be skipped.
      dontCacheBustUrlsMatching: /\.\w{8}\./,
      filename: 'service-worker.js',
      logger(message) {
        if (message.indexOf('Total precache size is') === 0) {
          // This message occurs for every build and is a bit too noisy.
          return;
        }
        if (message.indexOf('Skipping static resource') === 0) {
          // This message obscures real errors so we ignore it.
          // https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/2612
          return;
        }
        console.log(message);
      },
      minify: true,
      // For unknown URLs, fallback to the index page
      navigateFallback: publicUrl + '/index.html',
      // Ignores URLs starting from /__ (useful for Firebase):
      // https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/2237#issuecomment-302693219
      navigateFallbackWhitelist: [/^(?!\/__).*/],
      // Don't precache sourcemaps (they're large) and build asset manifest:
      staticFileGlobsIgnorePatterns: [/\.map$/, /asset-manifest\.json$/],
    }),
    // TypeScript type checking
    fs.existsSync(paths.appTsConfig) &&
    new ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin({
      typescript: resolve.sync('typescript', {
        basedir: paths.appNodeModules,
      }),
      async: false,
      checkSyntacticErrors: true,
      tsconfig: paths.appTsConfig,
      compilerOptions: {
        module: 'es6',
        moduleResolution: 'node',
        resolveJsonModule: true,
        // isolatedModules: true,
        // noEmit: true,
        jsx: 'react',
      },
      reportFiles: [
        '**',
        '!**/*.json',
        '!**/__tests__/**',
        '!**/?(*.)(spec|test).*',
        '!src/setupProxy.js',
        '!src/setupTests.*',
      ],
      watch: paths.appSrc,
      silent: true,
      formatter: typescriptFormatter,
    }),
  ].filter(Boolean),
  // Some libraries import Node modules but don't use them in the browser.
  // Tell Webpack to provide empty mocks for them so importing them works.
  node: {
    dgram: 'empty',
    fs: 'empty',
    net: 'empty',
    tls: 'empty',
    child_process: 'empty',
  },
  // Turn off performance processing because we utilize
  // our own hints via the FileSizeReporter
  // performance: false,
  // Intructs webpack to target a specific environment.
  // https://webpack.js.org/configuration/target/
  target: 'electron-renderer',
};
```

I have done some research and came across [this thread](https://discuss.atom.io/t/in-script-tag-is-interpreted-as-file/19232), however, I don't think that there is any solution given which is applicable to my problem.

How can I load those remote files from my production build?

Answer (score 0):

As already stated in [this comment over at the Atom.io thread you provided](https://discuss.atom.io/t/in-script-tag-is-interpreted-as-file/19232/4), by using `//` instead of, say, `https://` you request the URL over the current protocol.

It could possibly be that when you load a file into an Electron window in development directly, Electron (or, specifically, Chromium, since Electron only builds on top of that) will assume that the current protocol is HTTP and hence load the file. But if you load the file from a packaged app, your HTML source might be loaded via `file://`, which makes your URL invalid.

I suggest to use HTTPs anyways (if the endpoint provides encryption). Even if it's "only an image", encrypted connections and traffic can basically do no harm.

Also refer to [this explanation](https://www.paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/) on so-called "protocol-relative URLs", which yours is.